# Wordpress og:image shows up blank

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I've been at this for almost 3 days straight and now I can't even think clearly anymore.

All I'm trying to do is to get my featured image thumbnail to appear when I paste the link in Facebook.

- I'm using the Wordpress Facebook Open Graph protocol plugin which generates all the correct og meta properties.
- My thumbnail images are 240x200px which respects the minimum requirements and also respects the 3:1 ratio
- I've made sure there's no trailing slash at the end of my post URLs
- When I use the Facebook Object Debugger, the only warning is in regards to my locale, but that shouldn't affect it.
- Facebook appears to be pulling the right image, at least the URL is correct, but the image appears as a blank square

I've gone through pretty much every thread I could find in forums, but all the information available is about using the correct og tags, which I believe I'm already doing.

Thank you very very much for any help, I'm desperate!! :)

Comment: Is it possible there's cache issues? Can you turn your cache off and see if you get the same results?

Comment: Sorry, which cache are you referring to? Currently I don't have a caching plugin installed, I've cleared my browser's cache, also tried 3 different browsers and it's still a no go.

Comment: What exactly is the path you're specifying for your og:image tag? Are you using Wordpress functions to set the path? Show us the code you're using.

Comment: <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/nageoire-dauphin-240x200.jpg">

Comment: ^ This is how it renders using the WP plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can troubleshoot the OpenGraph meta tags with the Debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - this can at least show if you're using the meta tags properly and if Facebook can 'read' the image.

Comment: According to the debug tool, Facebook can read the image, the URL is correct but the image doesn't actually render, it's just a blank square (when I click it, it takes me to the correct image).

Comment: Here's a link to the FB Developer: 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdepensesfolles.com%2Fperimetre-securite-laser%2F

Comment: I thought I would share what ended up resolving it for me:

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that the root of my issue was the fact that I was using an addon domain (which is really a subdomain being redirected to the top level domain) and I read on eHow (of all places :) ) that Facebook has trouble pulling data from redirected domains.

Not sure if there was another way around it, but I simply ended up creating a seperate hosting account and everything is loading properly now.

Answer (score 0):

one problem youre going to run into testing is that often the first time your page or post gets liked, fb keeps whatever img it finds in your meta tags or by searching your page.  so, you'll keep changing your img meta tag and still it wont show the right pic.  it's very anoying.  One way to get around it is to change the slug of your post.  now, it has a different url and to fb, it's a different page.  The downside is you lose all the likes that go with your orig url.  Not a problem with a new site.

Answer (score 0):

I ended here googling another problem. Maybe this might help someone:

Please bear in mind that the facebook scraper works asynchronously and will need some time (during my tests **around 10 minutes**) to be able to display an image after seeing it for the first time.

For more information, [here's a more thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44873484/2072165) on a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as Andy Wibbels points out the FB debugger is a really handy tool.

I faced a similar issue with a server's og:image tag pointing to a secure subdomain which actually mirrors a CDN server,

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://subdomain.pathToImage.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image_secure" content="https://subdomain.pathToImage.jpg" />`

The FB [debugging tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) allows you to see the errors that FB encounters when trying to pull the image.

In my case the subdomain was not registered under the SSL certificate used by the HTTPS protocol.  Hence FB was getting the following error,

`Curl Error : SSL_CACERT SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`