# Facebook struggles to scrape one domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have already checked out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https), and it sounds like he's describing the same exact problem as me except for a few things:

1. I'm not running on https
2. 80% of the time I try to debug, I get this message " Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."
3. The scraper works perfectly on a different domain, but same server, same theme with almost identical content.  Every time I try a domain it scrapes it perfectly including the image

During the 20% that it actually scrapes my page, I am having the same issue in the above link.  It is reading my thumbnail, yet showing a blank image.  The link brings me to a working image but it doesn't want to show anything.

The weird part is it worked completely fine about 10 months ago when I updated this blog on a daily basis.  The only difference is I've switched servers recently.  While that would explain a possibility, the other domain switched as well and doesn't have this problem.

I am at a loss why my links either show no image at all in facebook or give me the:

Domain Link
Domain
(no image, no description)

Very frustrating situation.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Update:**

I have 6 domains...

When I moved servers recently, I found the new server wasn't prepared to compress the pages, so my blog posts looked crazy.  This forced me to turn compression 'off' on WP Super Cache on my main blog.  I also did it to my 2nd highest traffic blog figuring I'd get to the other 4 later.

Well, now those first two blogs appear to work fine in the facebook debugger, but the remaining 4 have troubles.   The tricky part is, I completely removed WP Super Cache from one site and still had trouble fetching the data.

So while it seems logically it should have been a WP Super Cache issue, continuing to have errors despite removing it leads me to believe now?  I'm still so baffled.

**Update:**
Ok, I loaded Chrome and IE, and both were able to pull the data with ease.  The google snippet tool also worked great.  I am going to try posting a link to my facebook fan page via chrome and see if it works correctly.

I did clear my FF cache and it didn't change, but I am still confused why one domain works ok while the other does not.  Either way, if adding in Chrome works, I'll stick with that for now.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Cache should not make any problem. If a browser can see your page, so can facebook debugger.
2. See if some 500 error is there. Try from different browser, clearing the browser cache etc. Try [google rich snippet](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) and see if a custom search engine is scrapping it fine.

PS: It will be nicer if you post url.

Comment: Sorry, I should have listed some links...

Using Firefox, I can put in a debug from any link any this domain teenmomjunkies.com and it works fine.  However, any time I put in a blog post from bigbbrotherjunkies.com I either get a) an error, b) error parsing URL or c) Finally filled out but not displaying an image. 

Thanks for any help.  After dinner I'll check your other suggestions