# Facebook sharer.php is not showing the image even when using the image tag

Tags: facebook

This article [article](http://www.chinadialogue.net/article/show/single/en/5212-Official-air-pollution-data-in-Beijing-still-failing-the-public) has an issue with Facebook. When I try to share the article with sharer.php Facebook does not work (try by clicking the Facebook icon). Most of the other articles are working fine. I am using the og:image tag, but with this article the image is not loaded.

UPDATE:

From this debugger I get: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Response Code:  206
Fetched URL:    https://s3.amazonaws.com/cd.live/uploads/content/image/5212/aside_main_air-pollution-day-2.jpg
Canonical URL:  https://s3.amazonaws.com/cd.live/uploads/content/image/5212/aside_main_air-pollution-day-2.jpg
Errors That Must Be Fixed

Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.

Comment: this morning 17 October 2012 Facebook is loading the image

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http:// instead of https:// for the og:image url?

Comment: All articles are using https to serve the images and for most of them images are loaded (in FB).

Comment: Or maybe the HTML-code in og:description is confusing facebook? I See <p> tags coming through. 

Sorry I'm guessing here, since it's difficult to test :)

Comment: And you might look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https

Comment: Either with HTTP and HTTPS I get the same error. I had a look at the bugs, I cannot find a way to open a new bug

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an S3 authentication key problem and not facebook's already deprecated sharer.php api (go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729324/title-doesnt-show-up-when-i-share-url-on-facebook/19095732#19095732) for more info). You'll need to look into your S3 auth and ensure that you can open up an image in your browser prior passing it onto FB's sharer.php.