# How to customize a netlify website’s social media preview?

Tags: web-deployment, netlify

I published a website (https://isugg20-crash-viz.netlify.app/#1) using Netlify and was wondering how I can add an image that will serve as my website’s social media preview when I share it on Facebook, LinkedIn, etc?

[Cross posted from Netlify Community](https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-customize-a-websites-social-media-preview/22927?u=ashirwad)

Comment: You have to add `<meta>` tags specific to each social media site inside the `<head>` of your HTML.  It's nothing special to do with Netlify.  Just google social media meta tags, you will find free tools to generate them for you easily.

Comment: @GirkovArpa, thanks for the pointer! From Google search I found https://metatags.io/ and generated the meta tags. But even after adding the meta tags, I don't see a preview when I try sharing the website link on Facebook or LinkedIn. Is it because it takes a while for these meta tags to get registered in Netlify's system?

Comment: The meta tags are present as you can see in the source code of your site, and working according to this: https://www.heymeta.com/url/isugg20-crash-viz.netlify.app

Comment: Huh, interesting! But when I try to share the link on say Facebook, the preview looks very  different! It's pulling one of the images from the slides and using that as a preview image. Do you know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: According to here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20262825/13378247 You were right about Facebook caching the old site.  So I recommend changing the Netlify URL of your site.  It's very easy and takes only a second.  If that doesn't help, maybe any of the numerous other answers can.

Comment: When I use Facebook's option *See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL*, it seems Netlify is not injecting the meta tags. But Hey Meta is able to read those tags. I don't know what's happening! I have communicated this to Netlify, hope I hear back from them soon.

Comment: Right-click on your page (while viewing it) and click "View Source".  You'll see the tags.  They're definitely there.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the tags are there! I am getting baffled now. I tried sharing the link on  LinkedIn also, but I don't see the social preview like I see on Hey Meta. I am going to sleep now and will investigate this tomorrow. Thanks for all your help.