# Facebook og: image appears blank

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I currently having a problem with FB OG image on Feed status of https://3dl.aut.ac.nz/.
On profile status. This works fine. It appears that the bug is only happening on HOME(news feed page) status

[image: Facebook Image Bug]

The site is built in wordPress. Normally I don't stuck on og image on my previous works on WordPress. 
On [fb object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), the site has the correct og image and seems no problem at all.

I suspect its because im using secure server? (https://) Also same thing happens if I try, http://3dl.aut.ac.nz/ (http).

I investigated this issue and found another similar thread on stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https). The thread says that this has been an issue with https. However, the facebook.com has a thumbnail when posted the link on FB status.

**Is this issue has something to do with the server settings?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https/http should be no problem, i suspect that the image is just too broad. Always use the correct aspect ratio and size: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.
>
> Try to keep your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible to display the full image in News Feed without any cropping.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem myself. You're trying to share from a secure site using Yoast's Wordpress SEO plugin. Unfortunately, it doesn't properly handle the meta tags for secure images. Yoast includes:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://image-url-here" />
```

Facebook doesn't like that, but there's an easy fix, by adding:

```
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://image-url-here" />
```

I [wrote up a blog post](http://toodlepip.co.uk/2017/how-to-fix-facebook-opengraph-images-on-secure-sites-with-wordpress/) on how to hook into the plugin's *wpseo_opengraph_image* hook to handle this automatically.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please bear in mind that the facebook scraper works asynchronously and will need some time (during my tests **around 10 minutes**) to be able to display an image after seeing it for the first time.

For more information, [here's a more thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44873484/2072165) on a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, converting a PNG graphic with transparency to no transparency fixed the error.

[Facebook API debug error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j01VD.png)