# Facebook doesn't recognize og:image:secure_url. Only uses og:image, which returns 404

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-opengraph

The website I am retrieving images from is only accessible through HTTPS. So when I use Facebook debugger to scrape the page, it is only showing og:image, and that nothing is being returned. I need it to use the og:image:secure_url, that is defined in my code, but Facebook debugger doesn't even bring it in. The website I am developing is currently non-https. Could this be the issue?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="246 COUGARTOWN Circle">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.builtincalgary.com/houses/details/?idhouse=1778551&issimplyrets=true/">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/creb/photos/80477609/1.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/creb/photos/80477609/1.jpg">
```

Comment: Just use og:image but put the https version there. Why do you need a http version?

Comment: I was using a compiled DLL that provided OpenGraph classes for Facebook, so I didn't have much of a choice without making the small change in their code and compiling that. 

I ended up just using a separate basic string for when the provided classes don't quite do what I want. You were right, removing the secure_url and just using image did the trick.

Comment: There seems to be a longstanding bug with Facebook not properly scraping og:image if the URL is https://. This is a question I'd like answered: if the only URL of the image is https do we use that URL for og:image and og:image:secure_url, or just for og:image:secure_url? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https