# Og:image not quickly scraped

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem with the recognition of the tag `og:image` in my site.

This is the code generated in my php app

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Fondazione dell'ordine degli psicologi dell'abruzzo onlus" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.ordinepsicologiabruzzo.it/images/img_jolly.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="243" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="227" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.ordinepsicologiabruzzo.it/news/in-primo-piano/fondazione-dell-ordine-degli-psicologi-dell-abruzzo-onlus.html" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Ordine degli Psicologi della regione Abruzzo" />
```

But in the facebook debugger tool the image is not taken quickly and fb advice me to use `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` but... these tags are here!

I have tried using the http (and not https) version of the site but is the same.

The website is: www.ordinepsicologiabruzzo.it and a lot of pages are just correctly scraped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https?rq=1

Comment: Facebook caches their data so you'll have to either wait, or reset it manually here for your website link. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ . I did it for you, in case you where wondering why it's working all of the sudden .

Comment: Right, I was trying to remember how I forced it the last time I did this! However, there is a https image bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images (possibly https?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https)

Comment: It's not only a https bug since with https deactivated it's not working too.

Answer (score 0):

Your website is not currently declaring `og-image` in the `head`. You can see this by visiting your [site](http://www.ordinepsicologiabruzzo.it) and viewing source. You'll notice that some of your **OpenGraph** tags are also missing their `content` value, including `og-image:type`, `og-image:width`, `og-image:height`.

[image]

If you check [Facebook's Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=www.ordinepsicologiabruzzo.it) tools, you will be told the same thing, that you are missing `og-image`.

Add the `og-image` tag, and just use `//` for the beginning of `content` link.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="//ordinepsicologiabruzzo.it/images/img_jolly.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Please visit this page https://www.ordinepsicologiabruzzo.it/news/in-primo-piano/psicologia-e-nuove-tecnologie-digitali-quali-implicazioni.html

You can see all meta here. What is the problem in this page? I have to share pages like this. Where OG are not fully filled i don't need to share.