# og:image keeps giving me corrupted image

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta

I have a website build in the CMS Joomla where i cannot get the Facebook sharing right. At least, the images that show up when you want to share a link in Facebook. It drives me honestly totally mad.

I have spent a couple of hours now getting this right, I tried everything, changing images file extension, making them smaller, bigger, the exact dimensions (even if that means cropping my picture) it all does not work.

Please take a look at this graph:
Than the warnings, all the images are giving me corrupted back. Which I don't understand, follow the links and you see the image appearing. I don't get it at all.

There also states below that I miss the og:description tag, but when you scroll down the og:description is there listed. I mean, is this tool even reliable?

I tried to share the link on my own facebook page, but it does not gives me the images I want to.

Somebody has a solution to this mess? It drives me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Facebook had an [issue in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https) that some SO users still encounter.

An answer suggests to the og:image:secure_url tag alongside the normal og:image tag. Adding more as much info as you can could also help facebook... Try filling a complete image description with these meta:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" /> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

I have double checked the images, and they do not seem to have any problems. So it is either the said facebook issue, or a weird redirect you are doing when facebook accesses the image. You could double check your server logs to make sure it handles the request as expected.

While I'm no facebook OG expert, I hope that this can help at least I slight bit.

Comment: @HuubS your comment set off a bot used for moderating comments. Also consider accepting only when it actually solves your problem. Accepting a wrong answer might mislead others searching for the same problem

Comment: @SurajRao Ah ok, sorry to trigger that. About the comment, I think this is actually the way to go but for some reason Facebook is really acting weird, sometimes accept it but most of the time not. I think it's just Facebook not cooperating with my server. So probably this works for 99% of the people, at least I hope.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have an answer for the corrupted image issue. As for the og:description issue, it looks like Facebook is inferring an og:description from the meta description of your page, even though a og:description is not *explicitly* defined in your HTML source.

To resolve this, if you add the following meta property to the head section of your page, and then re-scrape the page with the OpenGraph debugger, the og:description error should go away.

```
<meta property="og:description" content="SWZ haar missie is het bieden van ondersteuning op het gebied van zorg in de breedste zin van het woord aan de inwoners van Wassenaar." />
```

... and yes, this whole "og:..." thing is quite duplicative, but I believe that is by design so marketers can use a different description for Facebook postings than what they would use for SEO.

Best of luck, let me know if you have any questions.