# Would having a fresh website with SSL already avoid Open Graph problem?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, web, facebook-opengraph

After adding SSL certificate, Facebook is unable to fetch open graph metadata on my site, even though they exist. Even when there is `og:image:secure_url` as suggested in this answer of [FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images (possibly https?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858052/3416774), the [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fxn--qucu-hr5aza.com%2F) still be unable to fetch.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://xn--qucu-hr5aza.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/97Afv.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://xn--qucu-hr5aza.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/97Afv.jpg" />
```

So I wonder if simply deleting the website and then reinstall it would work? The domain and hosting IP would be the same.

<sup>Related: [Why can't Open Graph checker detect Open Graph data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57529664/3416774)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that, and it simply doesn't work.