# Why can't Open Graph checkers detect Open Graph data?

Tags: url, ssl-certificate, meta, facebook-opengraph

[My page](https://lyminhnhat.com/resources/productivity/recommended-software/?utm_source=SE%3A%20Overflow&utm_medium=Recommended%20software&utm_campaign=Getting%20help&utm_term=post%3A%20Why%20can't%20Open%20Graph%20checker%20detect%20Open%20Graph%20data%3F), after adding an SSL certificate ([Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)), cannot have preview fetched by Facebook or Twitter when sharing the link. I have followed [The Open Graph protocol](https://opengraphprotocol.org/) and include the following open graph tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Corner Timer: gently make you feel guilty on time-wasting apps" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://lyminhnhat.com/resources/productivity/corner-timer-gently-make-you-feel-guilty-on-time-wasting-apps/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Make you feel guilty for your unproductive curiosity" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@ooker777" />
<meta name="twitter:text:title" content="Corner Timer: gently make you feel guilty on time-wasting apps" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://lyminhnhat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Screenshot_2019-04-11-11-31-39.png?w=640" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
```

However, all 3 Open Graph checkers I use - [OpenGraphCheck.com](https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fqu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com%2Fbo-suu-tap-tu-dien-chuyen-nganh%2F), [Abhinay Rathore's Open Graph Tester](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/open-graph-tester/), [Facebook's Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fqu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com%2Fbo-suu-tap-tu-dien-chuyen-nganh%2F) - say that there is no Open Graph implement. There is one exception though: [Iframely's Embed Codes](http://debug.iframely.com/)

Since all three checkers have problem with this, probably this is not just a problem of of Facebook, as suggested in [FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images (possibly https?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8855361/3416774). Nevertheless, nothing changes even though I have tried using html links only, stripping end white space, using `<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">`.

[This person](https://www.reddit.com/r/SEO/comments/csjgav/why_cant_open_graph_checkers_detect_open_graph/) suggests that it can be a server issue. Do you know why this happens?

<sup>Related: [Would having a fresh website with SSL already avoid Open Graph problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57526891/3416774)</sup>

Comment: Did you try changing your text into all english first and see if it's working?

Comment: @whalesingswee yes, I test on my English domain as well. See my edit

Comment: as I checked here it should be server problem as well, the FB debugger can't scrape your website. It's returning blank, must have something to do with server configuration, is it a shared host or VPS?

Comment: You could also check this: https://redirectdetective.com/ it seems your website not ending somewhere it should be?

Comment: I use a shared hosting. Using that checker, I only get `An unknown error or HTTP state has occured. This will be investigated.`

Comment: Maybe changing hosts or talk to them will be the best way. Not quite sure which part has went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it seems that the crawler is just having a bug. I have my own canonical answer in this question, hope that helps someone: [FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images (possibly https?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57606813/3416774)