# How to know what bots of a website, if I have no root access to the hosting they will read?

Tags: bots, wireshark, facebook-opengraph, root-access

Recently I have problem with [Open Graph checkers unable to detect Open Graph data?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/124673/52079). It turns out that [the bots from the checkers are unable to access data](https://serverfault.com/q/980012/536315). However, since I have no root access to my shared hosting, I can't use wireshark to know the exact bots that connects to my hosting, therefore cannot ask the technician to help me.

So is there a way to know the bots? I really have no idea where to start. The site I want to know is https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

<sup>Related: [What is the bot in Facebook for Developers' Object Debugger?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/132927/63572)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see and identify all traffic to your website in the access logs generated by `apache`, `nginx`, `iss`, ...

Furthermore there are already a lot of tools out there which are able to parse and reflect the data in a human reabable format. e.g. [awstats](https://awstats.sourceforge.io/)