# How to get site link image to show up reliably when posting to social sites

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, reddit

Im trying to make it so that when a link (to a tour on our site) is posted to some social media site - I want an image for the tour and title/description to show up.

And I have spent a bunch of time on the og: settings.  But the images are just not showing up properly.

**OG settings**

These are the constructed **seattle link** og properties

```
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Explore Sunny Seattle">
    <meta property="og:description" content="We explored Seattle on the one day it was sunny!  Jump in!">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/PPBL/pike+place+at+night+cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:url" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/PPBL/pike+place+at+night+cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/PPBL/pike+place+at+night+cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="800">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="436">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://worldalive.tours/tourbeta/5da7af5c30a71c1a6d1b8a76">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="-">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

These are the constructed **Grand Canyon link** og properties.

```
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Grand Canyon">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Explore the greatest canyon on earth!">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/Grand+Canyon/cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:url" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/Grand+Canyon/cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/Grand+Canyon/cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="800">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="436">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://worldalive.tours/tourbeta/5db750c7e8f3f8710e8f2916">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="-">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

**Twitter**

On twitter I can post this link

https://worldalive.tours/tourbeta/5da7af5c30a71c1a6d1b8a76

and the image [shows up](https://twitter.com/WorldAliveTours/status/1191072725168640000?s=20).

But this other link doesnt bring up the image when I try and post it on twitter.

https://worldalive.tours/tourbeta/5db750c7e8f3f8710e8f2916

**Reddit**

Same thing as twitter. The Grand Canyon tour won't show the correct image but the seattle tour will.

https://www.reddit.com/user/worldalivedottours

**Facebook**

When I use the [sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) it sometimes works but I get an error message:

```
Provided og:image, https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/PPBL/pike+place+at+night+cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg could not be downloaded. This can happen due to several different reasons such as your server using unsupported content-encoding. The crawler accepts deflate and gzip content encodings.
```

And when I dig into that I am unable to find anything conclusive. One suggests zipping the content but its already a jpeg.  compression doesnt make sense.

When I post the link it used to not bring up the images but now it does.  However when I look at summaries of the posts it's not using those images but another one from the site (the banner).

https://www.facebook.com/worldalivetours/

I feel like im missing either something really small - or something really big. Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong? It seems that there is quite a [deep history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https) but there are a lot of "this worked for me" that I have tried and no luck.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde. I should really remove the SEO tag because its not about SEO/search rank.  I just want to look correct in social sites when people post links.  That being said the pivotal question around the SEO tag may be the same here because the code "appears" to be correct. It still might belong here because I have code auto generating these meta-tags and one example is working (in some places) and the other is not. Which makes me think I am doing something wrong in the html or construction of URLs.  What are your thoughts? Will definitely check out the webmasters.SE forum!

Comment: @JohnConde Another thing is that there is history of questions like this on this site - including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https - which didn't help me but seems to be suffering in a similar way.