# OpenGraph og:image is not showing

Tags: html, reactjs, image, facebook-opengraph

I am having some issues with the Open Graph meta tags for images that I have not been able to solve after about 2 hours of debugging.

Here are my tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/PNG/placeholder.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1280" />    
<meta property="og:image:height" content="720" />    
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
```

but it is not showing in the Facebook developer debugger as shown in the image below:

[image: Warnings]

here is the preview shown on the developer page:

[image: Preview]

I have tried many different methods of getting the image such as `content="https://nerdee.io/images/PNG/placeholder.png"`.
and
`content="/images/PNG/placeholder.png"`
with no luck

here is my file structure:
[image: File struct]

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https

Comment: While your og:image width and height tags say your image is 1280 by 720, when I download your image, placeholder.png, I was served a 2560 by 1440 image that’s 8.89 MB in size. Facebook’s [limit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/) is 8MB. Try scaling your image down and see what happens.

Comment: Also, use the full url for your `og:image`  – https://nerdee.io/images...

Comment: @RichDeBourke i have tried that with no luck

Comment: also, that is weird, the image is 720p on my machine

Comment: I see you have your image working for sharing on Facebook, but your image may still be too big for some of the messaging apps such as WhatsApp. There’s a theory that WhatsApp wants images sizes less than 300KB (not backed up by any data from WhatsApp website). You could try saving your image as a JPEG with a lower quality and subsampling settings. That should get the image to below 250KB. The image does lose a little bit of quality, but it’s not enough for people to notice.

Comment: I am currently getting a logo made so that should be small enough for an icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by [Rich Debourke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011984/rich-debourke) in a comment. the image was too large for the facebook api to handle. thank you all for answers.