# Facebook Open graph does not work with https links

Tags: https, facebook-opengraph

Facebook Open graph does not work with `https` links, unfortunately it works fine with the same `http` links, if the site does not support redirect from http to https, But if the site supports redirection, facebook open graph will not work.

I searched deeply about the topic and most of the questions did not have an explicit solution except for [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https) and I think he did not give me what I wanted

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Thank you, my question may not be explicit, but it is clear that I am have a problem with Facebook Open graph in the case of https links, my question is about a solution to this problem