# Why is the OG Image for this article not showing up when sharing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

This is not a duplicate of:
[FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images (possibly https?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https)

I tried everything there!

This is driving me crazy.  All of our articles share with images, but this one (and two others like it) are not.

https://pbswisconsin.org/news-item/its-criminal-milwaukeeans-call-for-speedier-lead-pipeline-removal-to-cut-childhood-poisoning/

The Facebook Linter shows that everything is 100% correct, and that there are no errors.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

If you share on linked in or twitter, the image appears.  It is just Facebook.

Here are the OG Tags for the page:

```
   <meta name="description" content="Wisconsin home lead investigations rarely test water amid focus on paint, while replacing all lead service lines in Milwaukee would take 70 years at the current pace."/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="'It's Criminal': Milwaukeeans Call for Speedier Lead Pipeline Removal to Cut Childhood Poisoning" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Wisconsin home lead investigations rarely test water amid focus on paint, while replacing all lead service lines in Milwaukee would take 70 years at the current pace." />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://wisconsinpublictv.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/health-water-lead-serviceline-milwaukee-almujaahid-3.jpg"/>
        <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://wisconsinpublictv.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/health-water-lead-serviceline-milwaukee-almujaahid-3.jpg" />
        <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
        <meta property="og:image:alt" content="Nazir Al-Mujaahid fills a water bottle from a water system as seen in a mirror above a kitchen sink." />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="1228"/>
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="691"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://pbswisconsin.org/news-item/its-criminal-milwaukeeans-call-for-speedier-lead-pipeline-removal-to-cut-childhood-poisoning/" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="PBS Wisconsin" />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="'It's Criminal': Milwaukeeans Call for Speedier Lead Pipeline Removal to Cut Childhood Poisoning" /><link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//pbswisconsin.org' />
```

I have tried changing the name of the image, resizing the image, changing the description, adding an alt.

It just always appears as a grey box.

Please, I'm begging you Stack Overflow, any ideas to try?

At the end of my rope.

Comment: it is most likely not the issue, but the og:image:width and height values are not correct. the image is 1920x1080.

Comment: "Working" articles such as https://pbswisconsin.org/news-item/one-year-since-blake-shooting-in-kenosha/ do not appear to have their OG image stored on Amazon S3, as the not working one here in question. So you will likely have to check your access control settings for that S3 bucket, it probably blocks access by the FB scraper.