NextJS 14 dynamic meta data not showing up
I'm new to Next.js and attempting to have each page render distinct metadata based on the database content. I experimented with the layout approach in the Next.js app directory, but I'm puzzled as to why it's pulling the metadata from the root layout instead of the layout within the subfolder directory.
here is my stucture

In my root layout i have a static layout here
export const metadata = {
  title: "My website",
  
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}

And in my article slug subfolder i have this layout using a dynamic approach (generateMetadata)
export const generateMetadata = async ({
  params: { slug },
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
}): Promise<Metadata> => {
  // fetch data
  const { fetchArticle } = useArticle();
  const article = (await fetchArticle(slug)) as ArticleInterface;
  
  return {
    title: article.title,
     
  };
};

export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <>{children}</>;
}

Here is the useArticle content
var api: string;
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    api = `https://${process.PRODUCTION_URL}/api/articles?query=`;
  } else {
    api = "http://localhost:3000/api/articles?query=";
  }

  async function fetchArticle(slug: string) {
    const response = await fetch(`${api}${slug}`, {
      next: { revalidate: 60 },
    });
    const article = await response.json();
    if (Array.isArray(article) && article.length > 0) {
      return article[0];
    }
    return null;
  }


What's the value for the article object you're fetching? Do you really have something coming back from the server? The implementation seems to be correct. Have you checked the next server logs? No error in there?

@Sunamin34 everything seems good with the article object its returning everything correctly no error logs, what i observe is it showing correctly on localhost but when deployed in vercel its not showing the article/[slug] layout instead its showing the rootlayout.

Ok found the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https?rq=2, turns out i was using a share button that is not https i just updated it to https and seems all meta data including opengraph worked.
